# Home network does not open some websites only on ubuntu

Tags: networking, 20.04, network-manager

My home network stopped opening some websites like youtube.com on Ubuntu 20.04.02 LTS.

After lots of tweeks I **reinstalled** the whole OS (Ubuntu 20.04) and it's still the same

Also my openconnect doesn't resolve these domains after connecting to the vpn server.

Firefox and Chrome both give me same result

I installed windows 10 and it's ok in there.
Also if I USB tether my home network using my phone it also works without any problem.
**It's ok anywhere but on my Ubuntu even if I reinstall the OS**

Any thoughts where should I look for the problem?

I tried:

1. Changing my DNS
2. Flushing my DNS cache
3. Reinstalling the OS
4. Connecting to a VPN
5. Changing browsers
6. Resetting my home router to default settings

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp2s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 0c:9d:92:58:37:e7 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.116/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute enp2s0
       valid_lft 84251sec preferred_lft 84251sec
    inet6 fda8:e544:6612:d200:7904:3822:8e17:b552/64 scope global temporary dynamic 
       valid_lft 6924sec preferred_lft 3324sec
    inet6 fda8:e544:6612:d200:4d1e:3f2e:65f7:7d63/64 scope global dynamic mngtmpaddr noprefixroute 
       valid_lft 6924sec preferred_lft 3324sec
    inet6 2a01:5ec0:1000:db21:7904:3822:8e17:b552/64 scope global temporary dynamic 
       valid_lft 6924sec preferred_lft 3324sec
    inet6 2a01:5ec0:1000:db21:26bf:7826:61d6:eeee/64 scope global dynamic mngtmpaddr noprefixroute 
       valid_lft 6924sec preferred_lft 3324sec
    inet6 fe80::c0cc:9615:65bc:92a8/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: wlp3s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 80:c5:f2:05:63:01 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
11: tun0: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1434 qdisc fq_codel state UNKNOWN group default qlen 500
    link/none 
    inet 10.10.10.169/32 scope global tun0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::eaed:7e42:8bc5:2241/64 scope link stable-privacy 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         0.0.0.0         0.0.0.0         U     0      0        0 tun0
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    20100  0        0 enp2s0
10.10.10.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 tun0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 tun0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 enp2s0
193.29.56.138   192.168.1.1     255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 enp2s0
```

Comment: Can you update your question to show the output of `ip a` and `route -n`? This will show some network-specific information that might help answer the question.

Comment: @Matigo Updated my answer thanks.